# "How to record a script in Jmeter using VPN server"

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I'm new in JMeter and I am using the JMeter5.1 and I want to know about that how to record the script in JMeter through  VPN Server?
I want to record the script in using this command line:-**jmeter.bat -H  -P  -u  -a  -N** 
But I'm facing a some issue.That website run only Firefox browser without proxy. that's why I'm not able to record the script.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do this but there is no enough information in your question. Can you give more details so the other can try to help!
What is your situation? Are you tying to record an application on the same network as JMeter or a different network...?

My only experience with using VPN was when I had to record via VPN few times using a work laptop from a hotel room. I was able to do so, but I got few weird issues about JMeter browser trust certification, so I had to remove it and re-install it again.

Comment: I'm recording one website Which run only VPN server without proxy and I'm using this command line for recording the script :-jmeter.bat -H <Your Proxy Address> -P <Your proxy Port Number> -u <Your VPN username> -a <Your VPN Password> -N <Localhost>. But I'm not able to record the script. and how to set the proxy in Firefox to record the script.